# Why is query NOT using my index?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [LB].[Orders]
(
    [OrderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MasterOrderID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC)
) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PK_Index]  
    ON [BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders] ([OrderDate]); 

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_OrderID_OrderDate]  
    ON [BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders] ([OrderDate],[OrderID]);
```

I am trying to speed up this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [BTP_NYA].[XX].[Orders] WHERE [OrderDate] = '20170921' AND [OrderID] = 62192
```

Why does this query NOT USE my IX_OrderID_OrderDate Index? How else can I make is faster?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.4232.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0032831" StatementText="SELECT * FROM [BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders] WHERE [OrderDate]=@1 AND [OrderID]=@2" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x547011333B745205" QueryPlanHash="0xD16E72141B86DC03" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition" CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="144">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="836385" EstimatedPagesCached="209096" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="12369" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="59123">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderDate" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="Status" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderID" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderDate" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="Status" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Index="[PK_MasterOrderID]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                <SeekPredicates>
                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                    <SeekKeys>
                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                        <RangeColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderID" />
                        </RangeColumns>
                        <RangeExpressions>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@2],0)">
                            <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="@2" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Convert>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </RangeExpressions>
                      </Prefix>
                    </SeekKeys>
                  </SeekPredicateNew>
                </SeekPredicates>
                <Predicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders].[OrderDate]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[@1],0)">
                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[BTP_NYA]" Schema="[LB]" Table="[Orders]" Column="OrderDate" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Convert DataType="date" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Column="@1" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Convert>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@2" ParameterCompiledValue="(62192)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(62192)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="'20170921'" ParameterRuntimeValue="'20170921'" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: What is output for dbcc show_statistics

Comment: Try following : [OrderDate] = CONVERT(datetime, '20170921')

Comment: Why are you trying to speed this up? How long does it currently take?

Comment: **See Also**: [Why don't I get an index seek?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/176763/31340) which will be the case if your index doesn't [cover the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns)

Answer (score 23):

The reason the non-clustered index is not used is because it is more efficient to select the single row using the unique primary key clustered index. You can't get any faster than that to select all columns for a single row (barring a hash index on an in-memory table).

Comment: I agree with the answer. Completely true.. in addition ,  if you want to use the index spesific you want at the index must the index force https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/

Answer (score 2):

It does a clustered index seek on PK_MasterOrderID.

This is because you do `select *` and IX_OrderID_OrderDate doesn't include any columns.

If you would create the index with

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_OrderID_OrderDate]  
ON [BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders] ([OrderDate],[OrderID]) INCLUDE([all], [selected], [columns]);
```

, it would be used.

Comment: As said, the use of * prevents it from using the index because the desired columns are not included in the index. select * should be avoided for production queries as it can cause major performance problems.